# Eclipse and Team City plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, teamcity, integration

I am using Eclipse for Java developers and Team City for continuous integration and tortoiseSVN for my repository. I have installed all the necessary plugins but whenever I choose **TeamCity->Remote run** from eclipse I get the following message:

**No suitable modified files found for Remote Run.**

Any ideas what might be missing from my configuration ?

Comment: Is there any change in your stream that team city hasn't already built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... I was doing a *commit and push*. In order for the **Remote Run** option to work you first need to commit in your local repository then **Remote Run** and *push* if the tests are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Have you  checked that you've properly configured your build path and server pointing to TortoiseSVN

Under > Administration > Project > Create Build Configuration > VCS>  New VCS Root>

Ensure Connection from CI Server after using appropriate Username and password

Hope this helps

Comment: I have done this and the connection works fine. It seems that the tortoisesvn is the problem I will give it a try with Git.